# Can 1/4" waterproof Hardieboard be used for shower wall IF it is attached to 1/2" waterproof Hardieboard?

Tags: shower, tile, waterproofing

My contractor improperly installed my shower pan by first putting up the 1/2 Hardi and then installing the pan without attaching to the studs (as per the instructions with the pan). Now I don't have a flat plane to be able to take the tile down past the lip of the pan. Is it an option to, drill through the pan lip, and Hardi board into the stud to attach and then put another 1/4" (can't be 1/2" or it will make my shower enclosure not fit on the pan)on top so I have a proper alignment to the pan to put on the tile (and still take the tile over the flange/lip of pan). Is that a good fix or is tearing everything apart the only good answer?

Comment: The contractor should fix the problem at their expense if they did not follow the equipment directions. Deviating from instructions could mean voiding the warranty on the equipment, or insurance denial if problems develop down the road.

Comment: Triplefault is right, no need to go any farther than that. The tile guy/contractor needs to make it right on his dime or if he resists fire him for no confidence, which I would be inclined to do since these are steps ANY tile guy should do instinctively. I wouldn't let him carry on, but if he can convince you to let him keep going, I can only hope that 5-10 years down the road when or if symptoms start to show, well, that they never do....